# How do I count the number of directories in a path using bash?

Tags: bash

I'm using

```
DIRS=$(find . -type d)
```

to get get all directories recursively. Now I need to look at that list and print only the paths that have more than n number of directories. So I need to search for the '/' character in the path, but the methods I'm using to search for it aren't working.

Comment: You want to find all directories which have a depth larger than some value?

Comment: this answer is partially relevant (disclaimer: it's my answer to a related question): http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83598/7832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this also work for you?

```
DIRS=$(find . -type d -mindepth $n)
```

The command `find .` simply lists all files and directories in the current directory, recursively. Using `-type d`, we restrict it to list directories only. Using `-mindepth $n`, we require that each directory it at depth at least `$n` (set e.g. `n=2`, or just substitute the number directly instead of `$n`). See `man find` for more information.

The `$(...)` construct runs the given command and is substituted by its output; it is roughly equivalent to `` `...` ``. Finally, this output is assigned to the `DIRS` variable.

Comment: You should always explain you answer

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone explain how this works. Bash newb here.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way of doing this would be to do

> find . -type d -links +2

This will find all directories with more than 2 hard links. A subdirectory adds one hardlink to its parent directory, plus you have a hard link for '.' and '..'.